# How to modify the criteria part and get location by GPS automatically in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to set that the device prefer to choose to get location by GPS rather than network provider, but the device still always using network provider to get location. How can I modify the criteria part and get location by GPS automatically?

The criteria I am using:

```
public void getLocationProvider()   
  {   
    try   
    {   
      Criteria mCriteria01 = new Criteria();   
      mCriteria01.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);   
      mCriteria01.setAltitudeRequired(false);   
      mCriteria01.setBearingRequired(false);   
      mCriteria01.setCostAllowed(true);   
      mCriteria01.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);   
      strLocationProvider =    
      mLocationManager01.getBestProvider(mCriteria01, true);   

      mLocation01 = mLocationManager01.getLastKnownLocation   
      (strLocationProvider);   
    }   
    catch(Exception e)   
    {   
      mTextView01.setText(e.toString());   
      e.printStackTrace();   
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the criteria to `getBestProvider()` and hope that it will be a GPS-based service, you can use the criteria to return *all* matching providers, iterate through them looking for a GPS-based compatible service, and use the one you find:

First, grab all matching providers for your criteria:

```
List<String> allMatchingProviders = 
mLocationManager01.getProviders(mCriteria01, true);
```

Then iterate through the list and test each provider for satellite-based service:

```
foreach provider (allMatchingProviders)
{
    ...
    if( provider->requiresSatellite() == true )
        strLocationProvider = provider
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would any crash occur when there are many provider suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, this was intended as a shell to go on...you're correct that you'll need error handling that this does not illustrate. For example, it's entirely possible that there *won't* be a GPS location provider in the list, in which case you'll need a fallback plan (getBestProvider?).

As far as some sort of exception due to a sheer number of providers in the list...I doubt it. I don't know if the Location Manager would throw a specific exception in such a case, but I suppose it doesn't hurt to protect yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know how to do that. Any simpler method or example?